# Do I need to stop the CircularProgressIndicator if it is fully covered by a FadeInImage?

Tags: flutter

This is the example of `FadeInImage` from
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            Center(
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The `CircularProgressIndicator` display while FadeInImage is loading. However, I can not find a way to hide the `CircularProgressIndicator` after the image loaded.
Is there any performance impact if I don't hide the CircularProgressBar if it is fully covered by another View in Flutter, especially when my screen loads many images?

Comment: if you add `debugPrintBeginFrameBanner = true;` do you see the banner in the logs on each frame (every 16ms)?

Comment: @pskink thank you, the banner in the logs keep print forever even it's fully covered. then I think I can not use the CircularProgressIndicator with FadeInImage. I will use `FadeInImage` with an asset gif loading instead

Comment: you could remove that indicator but the problem is that `FadeInImage` does not provide any callback saying: "good, I have loaded the image completely"